# How can i retrieve a X509Certificate2 using the X509SerialNumber?

Tags: c#, xml, x509certificate, sign

I need to retrieve the X509Certificate2 that was used to sign an xml document, is there a way to do that using the serial number?

Already have the X509SerialNumber from the XML document, but its not the same serial number that i get from the X509Certificate2 object.

Thanks.